# Bean of type org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to update our Spring Boot project. The problem is that as soon as I do this the following error occurs that we can't get fixed:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.app.configuration.WebAppSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService' that could not be found.
```

You can also already see it red underlined in IntelliJ. Before the update it worked fine like it is.

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class WebAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

  @Autowired
  public WebAppSecurityConfig(OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService) {
    this.oidcUserService = oidcUserService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // authenticate user through azure AD
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .regexMatchers(
            "/app/(cockpit|admin|tasklist|welcome)/([^/]+)/",
            "/rest/([^/]+)")
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
  }

  /** Register camunda filter for authentication */
  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<ContainerBasedAuthenticationFilter>
      containerBasedAuthenticationFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<ContainerBasedAuthenticationFilter> filterRegistration =
        new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    filterRegistration.setFilter(new ContainerBasedAuthenticationFilter());
    filterRegistration.setInitParameters(
        Collections.singletonMap(
            "authentication-provider",
            "com.test.app.filter.SpringSecurityAuthenticationProvider"));
    filterRegistration.setOrder(
        101); // make sure the filter is registered after the Spring Security Filter Chain
    filterRegistration.addUrlPatterns("/app/*");
    filterRegistration.addUrlPatterns("/rest/*");
    return filterRegistration;
  }
}


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService' in your configuration.
```

Our current Spring Boot version is 2.3.12.RELEASE and we want to update to 2.5.x.

If we just do `new OidcUserService()` for the `.oidcUserService` the application is able to run but the login page only forewards to an empty Login with OAuth 2.0 page instead of redirecting to the Microsoft login page.

We already tried to disable some dependencies like other similar questions did. Does anybody have an idea what happenend that the bean cannot be found?

The updated **pom.xml** looks like this (we had to switch from `azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter` to `spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory`):

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <version.camunda>7.16.0-ee</version.camunda>
        <springBoot.version>2.5.14</springBoot.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.2</log4j2.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
                <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>${version.camunda}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-engine</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.camunda.connect</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camunda-connect-connectors-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.connect</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-connect-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-engine-plugin-spin</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-spin-dataformat-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventhubs</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <!--                    <version>${springBoot.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            <!--            <version>${springBoot.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.9.0-M1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.24</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

An excerpt from the **application.yml**:

```
spring:
  jersey: application-path=/rest

  profiles:
    active: dev

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./camunda-h2-database

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          azure-oauth-provider:
            authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/${spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id}/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/${spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id}/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/${spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id}/openid/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/${spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id}/discovery/keys
        registration:
          azure:
            client-id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
            client-secret: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
            provider: azure-oauth-provider
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        profile:
          tenant-id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        user-group:
          allowed-group-names: Users

server:
  forward-headers-strategy: native # correctly handle X-Forwarded-Proto header to properly construct Azure AD redirect url

default:
  baseUrl: http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this dependency because in your application.yml file you have mentioned that auth-provider (authorization-uri: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/${spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id}/oauth2/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/$%7Bspring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id%7D/oauth2/authorize)) so it might help:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Does not help. I've added this dependency but nothing changed.

Comment: If i use version 4.0.0 of spring-cloud it seems to work. Before I have tried 5.0.0 and it didn't worked. Maybe they have changed something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using Spring 2.6.7:
https://github.com/rob2universe/azure-active-directory-oauth-spring-boot

Your problem may be that you are not letting the framework **inject the oicdUserService** as shown here:
https://github.com/rob2universe/azure-active-directory-oauth-spring-boot/blob/6db04d4f5a15f1d2f8f59365ef54c3da992c6d78/src/main/java/com/example/aad/AADOAuth2LoginSecurityConfig.java#L18

Also note the MS resources referenced in the readme.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me that I was adding other libraries like resource-server dependencies. Spring Azure then start to identify my application with a type of web_application_and_resource_server, so it does not provide the OidcUserService bean. What I did was to force my application with a type of web_application like so.

```
-Dspring.cloud.azure.active-directory.application-type=web_application
```

This way, Spring configuration started to inject properly OidcUserService, problem solved.